# FOR UPDATE NOWAIT doesn't work

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are two queries:

1.

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM "Users"
WHERE "Users"."Name" = 'user0'
FOR UPDATE NOWAIT ;

select pg_sleep(30);

END;
```

2.

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE "Users"
SET "Respect" = 2
WHERE "Users"."Name" = 'user0';
END;
```

As I use NOWAIT I expect that the second query will return error but it doesn't work for me. The second query just hangs and waits for the first one. What did I miss? I tried on 9.2-9.4 Postgres.

Comment: Offcourse, the NOWAIT is for your 1st transaction, not the second one. You're using NOWAIT in the wrong transaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOWAIT affects the statement it's in. It doesn't affect other statements that *want* to wait rather than reporting an error.

To have your *second* query immediately raise an error if it can't lock rows, you'll need to rewrite it to use `select ... for update nowait`, then `update...`. The update statement alone doesn't have a nowait option.

```
BEGIN transaction;
select "Respect" from "Users" where "Name" = 'user0' for update nowait;

UPDATE "Users"
SET "Respect" = 2
WHERE "Users"."Name" = 'user0';
END;
```

Comment: But..is there a way to get a row to be locked for my case. I mean the case when the first one transaction do lock on row and 2st transaction tries to update the same row and gets an error?

Comment: That's what my answer does. If your first query locks a row my answer needs, my answer will raise an error immediately. It won't wait for other transactions to release their locks. You can test this by running `psql` in two terminal windows (for example).